# Cannot transfer a dropped file to standard file input in Microsoft edge version 18 or below

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, microsoft-edge

Transferring a dropped file to standard file input works very well in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but again these Microsoft Browsers are making a problem. Somehow in Microsoft Edge version 17, 18, and below, a dropped file is not transferred and I am looking for any possible way to move the dropped file to standard file input. I would appreciate any idea. Please, find my code below:

```
function uploadWithDragAndDrop() {
    var dragCounter = 0;

    // Drag enter
    jQuery('#pageWrapper .contentArea').on('dragenter', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // Disabling drag and drop option when Web (Labeled) tab is active
        if (isWebLabeledTabActive()) {
            return;
        }

        dragCounter++;
        scrollToFileDropArea();
        addStyleAttribute();
    });

    // Drag over
    jQuery('#pageWrapper .contentArea').on('dragover', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        if (isWebLabeledTabActive()) {
            return;
        }

        scrollToFileDropArea();
        addStyleAttribute();
    });

    // Drag leave
    jQuery('#pageWrapper .contentArea').on('dragleave', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        dragCounter--;

        if (dragCounter === 0) {
            removeStyleAttribute();
        }
    });

    // Mouse leave
    jQuery('#pageWrapper .contentArea').mouseleave(function () {
        removeStyleAttribute();
    });

    // Drop
    jQuery('#pageWrapper .contentArea').on('drop', function (eventObject) {
        eventObject.stopPropagation();
        eventObject.preventDefault();

        if (isWebLabeledTabActive()) {
            return;
        }

        removeStyleAttribute();
        transferFile(eventObject);
    });
}

function transferFile(eventObject) {
    var files = eventObject.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var i, fileName;

    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fileName = files[i].name;
    }
    
    var fileInput = ".file-upload-area input[type='file']:first";

    if (isBrowserSafari()) {
        jQuery(fileInput).prop("files", files);
    } else {
        jQuery(fileInput).prop("files", files).trigger('change');
    }
}
```

When I debugged the code in the new version of the Edge (Version 83.0.478.56 - May, 2020) and in 17 (42.17134 - March, 2018). I see the object (the dropped file) and its proto is null:
[image] [image]

Comment: whether you are using the drag or drop plugin or not? Can you create a [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/pen/) (include the html resource and the related Javascript script) to reproduce the problem? it is better for us to help you reproduce the problem and solve it.

Comment: I am not using any DnD plugin, it is a pure jQuery code. Please, find the example in code pen: https://codepen.io/dostonhamrakulov/pen/JjGOjaY and I have put all of the code there.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the example on my side. First, since the Microsoft Edge 83 is chromium based, the example works well. but if I use Edge 18 version, it will show the "Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode"  error. it seems that we can't drag files to the file type input elements (because it is read-only). After change the file type input element to a div tag, the code works well in the legacy version Microsoft Edge. Second, from the [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRj0o.png), we can see that even the inner `_proto_` property is null, but we can see that the outer `_proto_` property is not null, so we could get the drop files and [preview the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SroqV.png).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Great to know that it worked for you. But I have not got the full idea, like what did you mean by “After change the file type input element to a div tag” ? could you please share the code?

Comment: I mean change " <input type="file" id="media-resource-file" style="display: none" onchange="document.getElementById('preview-image').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" /> " to "<div id="media-resource-file" style="display: none" onchange="document.getElementById('preview-image').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" > </div>".

Comment: Great, I have just tested in Browserstack, and this worked well for Edge 18. Thank you a lot